# Importing World Bank data for all countries in a region using the WDI package

Tags: r

I am using the `R` package `WDI` which allows importing of World Bank data through their API. The problem is that I want to look at all countries in a region, e.g. Sub-Saharan Africa. However for this I need to specify so many countries (SSH is 49 right now).

To start with this is inefficient, especially considering that the data explorer on data.worldbank.org does allow you to select a region.

However the real problem is that the number of countries becomes problematic to handle for (I' m guessing) the World Bank API, because a too-large number of countries gives an HTTP error. Causing me to have to split the request in two parts.

However, when using the more efficient `ALL` value there is no error, even though the number of observations is a lot higher.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
library(WDI)

COUNTRIES1 <- c( "AGO","BEN","BWA","BFA","BDI","CMR","CPV","CAF","TCD","COM","ZAR","COG","CIV","GNQ","ERI","ETH","GAB","GMB","GHA","GNB","GIN","KEN","LSO","LBR","MDG" )
COUNTRIES2 <- c( "MWI","MLI","MRT","MUS","MYT","MOZ","NAM","NER","NGA","RWA","STP","SEN","SYC","SLE","SOM","ZAF","SSD","SDN","SWZ","TZA","TGO","UGA","ZMB","ZWE" )
INDICATORS <- c("NY.GDP.PCAP.KN", "SP.DYN.TFRT.IN", "SP.POP.TOTL")

LONG1 <- WDI( country=COUNTRIES1, indicator=INDICATORS, start=1960, end=2009, extra=FALSE)
LONG2 <- WDI( country=COUNTRIES2, indicator=INDICATORS, start=1960, end=2009, extra=FALSE)

LONG <- merge( LONG1, LONG2, by=intersect( names(LONG1),names(LONG2) ), all=TRUE )
```

I have tried using `SSH` as a country code, but this gives an aggregate of all SSH countries, rather than all the observations.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the data for all countries
and use the `Region` to filter the results.

```
library(WDI)
indicators <- c("NY.GDP.PCAP.KN", "SP.DYN.TFRT.IN", "SP.POP.TOTL")
d <- WDI("all", indicators, extra=TRUE, start=1960, end=2009)
# Discard unwanted rows
d <- d[ which(d$Region == "Sub-Saharan Africa"), ]
# Discard unwanted columns
d <- d[,1:6]
head(d)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just if somebody else wants to use this, you can drop the extra columns using:

  `d <- subset(d, select=c("country", "year", indicators))`